# mapstruct duplicating code in another field

Tags: java, spring-boot, mapstruct

I just want to apply the generateToken method to the Token field, but mapstruct is forcing login too, how to solve this?

```
@Mapper(uses = MapperGenerateToken.class)
public interface TelemarketerAccountMapper {
TelemarketerAccountMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper( TelemarketerAccountMapper.class );

@Mapping(expression = "java(MapperGenerateToken.generateToken(assistant.getLogin()))", target = "token")
@Mapping(source = "assistant.login", target = "login")
AuthenticatedTelemarketerAccount map(TelemarketerAccount assistant);
```

Genetated code:

```
    @Override
public AuthenticatedTelemarketerAccount map(TelemarketerAccount assistant) {
    if ( assistant == null ) {
        return null;
    }

    AuthenticatedTelemarketerAccount authenticatedTelemarketerAccount = new AuthenticatedTelemarketerAccount();

    authenticatedTelemarketerAccount.setLogin( MapperGenerateToken.generateToken( assistant.getLogin() ) );

    authenticatedTelemarketerAccount.setToken( MapperGenerateToken.generateToken(assistant.getLogin()) );

    return authenticatedTelemarketerAccount;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

MapStruct has the concept of reusing user defined mappings defined in other mappers defined via `Mapper#uses`.

There are 2 ways that you can solve this:

### Use of qualifiers

In your `MapperGenerateToken#generateToken` method you can use the MapStruct `@Named` annotation and use that in the mapping.

e.g.

```
public class MapperGenerateToken {

    @Named("generateToken")
    public static String generateToken(String login) {
        // your custom logic
    }
}
```

```
@Mapper(uses = MapperGenerateToken.class)
public interface TelemarketerAccountMapper {
    TelemarketerAccountMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper( TelemarketerAccountMapper.class );

    @Mapping(target = "token", source = "login", qualifiedByName = "generateToken")
    AuthenticatedTelemarketerAccount map(TelemarketerAccount assistant);
}
```

this is going to generate the code that you expect.

Note: The second `@Mapping` is not needed since MapStruct will detect the mapping for the login automatically.

### Use of `Mapper#imports`

If you still want to use expression then you can use `Mapper#imports` to tell MapStruct to only import that class and not use it to look up for mapping methods.

e.g.

```
@Mapper(uses = MapperGenerateToken.class)
public interface TelemarketerAccountMapper {
    TelemarketerAccountMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper( TelemarketerAccountMapper.class );

    @Mapping(target = "token", expression = "java(MapperGenerateToken.generateToken(assistant.getLogin()))")
    AuthenticatedTelemarketerAccount map(TelemarketerAccount assistant);
}
```

---

I would strongly suggest the use of the first approach using qualifiers.